# Проблемы с java: char

Tags: java, циклы, char

Нужно написать код, который запрашивает у пользователя ввести 5 разных char и в конце, если хотя бы один из введенных char это буква 'a' вывести True, если нет 'а' - False

Что у меня вышло:

```
public class Control{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        char y = 'a';
        for (int x = 0; x<5; x++){
        System.out.print("Insert......:");
        char n = SIn.readNonwhiteChar();
            if (n == y)
                System.out.println("True");
            else
                System.out.println("False");
            
        }
    }
}
```

Но, этот код работает немного не так как нужно, он выводит False/True после каждого char, а не после всех:

```
C:\Users\SNBPC\LabProg>java Control
Insert......:e
False
Insert......:r
False
Insert......:a
True
Insert......:w
False
Insert......:a
True
```

Если же сделать вот так:

```
public class Control{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        char y = 'a';
        for (int x = 0; x<5; x++){
        System.out.print("Insert......:");
        char n = SIn.readNonwhiteChar(); 
            }                                    //чтобы убрать if/else из цикла
            if (n == y)  
                System.out.println("True");
            else
                System.out.println("False");
    }
}
```

То выходит ошибка что невозможно найти n. И я не знаю как его продублировать опять.

```
C:\Users\SNBPC\LabProg>javac Control.java
Control.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                    if (n == y)
                        ^
  symbol:   variable n
  location: class Control
1 error
```

Помогите.

Comment: Либо всё сохранять в какую-то коллекцию, а после ввода проверять коллекцию на наличие `'a'`, либо перед заполнением завести какой-нибудь флаг, при вводе каждого символа проверять этот символ и менять флаг при необходимости, после окончания ввода проверить флаг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создадим переменную `isA` типа `boolean` вне метода `main`. Каждый новый ввод будем сравнивать значение введённого символа с данным (`char y`), если они равны, то `isA` станет равным `true`: `false ИЛИ true = true`, `true ИЛИ true = true`. После ввода проверим и выполним необходимые действия:

```
public class Control {

    static char y = 'a';
    static boolean isA = false;

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        for (int x = 0; x<5; x++) {
            char n = SIn.readNonwhiteChar();
            isA = isA || (n == y);
            System.out.print("Insert......:");
        }
        if (isA)
            System.out.println("True");
        else
            System.out.println("False");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.
Только можете объяснить подробнее что делает эта часть кода
`isA = isA || (n == y);`

Comment: Уже есть в ответе: это логический оператор `ИЛИ`. возвращает `true`, если хотя бы один из операнд равен `true`